# Symfony Doctrine using dashes in column names for joinColumns

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having trouble implementing doctrine for our website which runs mysql.

Basically, the problem is in using dashes in column names.

We're using a standard way of naming our tables and column names, here's an example: `vendor_point-of-sale`. Upon reading the name you already know more or less what the link between those two means, the point of sale entity is linked to the vendor entity.

In my example on `vendor` table I have a column named `point-of-sale_id` and similarly, the `point-of-sale` table has a primary key also called `point-of-sale_id`. The problem with that is happening only when I try to call `findBy` on the `vendor` entity, it simply doesn't create the child object and (I checked the logs) there are no calls to the `point-of-sale` table.

The basic object querying ([official doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)) on the `point-of-sale` entity works fine if I add the identifier quoting as described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words).

Here's some code:

Vendor.orm.yml:

```
     Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\VendorApiKey:
     ...
     pointOfSale:
            targetEntity: PointOfSale
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                point_of-sale_id:
                    name: `point-of-sale_id`
                    referencedColumnName: point-of-sale_id
            orphanRemoval: false
    ...
```

After a `findBy` all I want to do is this:

```
$vendor->getPointOfSale()
```

Unfortunately, this returns `NULL`. It is giving me a mysql exception if I don't put the quotes.

I wanted to post on their forums and probably create bug request, but I want to hear what you have to say about this first.

Thank you, all suggestions on how I can make this work are greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Upon further reading I stumbled upon [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#identifier-quoting-and-legacy-databases). This doesn't make any sense... If I remove the quotations, it gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.point' in 'field list'
```

Does this mean outdated documentation? I'm confused.

Comment: If it's not supported, we'll probably convert to camel case, but I want to make sure that it's 100% the case. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html), dashes are not standard.  Experience has shown that `field_name` in the database is converted by Doctrine to `fieldName`.  So maybe replace dashes with underscores?

Comment: I could, but then having `vendor_point_of_sale` loses the whole reading magic of something like this: `vendor_point-of-sale`